# Eclipse Err: the source attachment does not contain the source for the file remotewebdriver.class

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Problem:
I'm trying to **debug** a simple test in Eclipse (using **selenium web driver 3.4.0, testng, FF 53, chrome latest**) but get this exception:
"the source attachment does not contain the source for the file remotewebdriver.class" as soon as this line is reached "WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();"

Setup:

I downloaded the latest selenium web driver for java from here: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-java-3.4.0.zip
2. Extracted and copied all jar files to one folder "d:\jars\"
3. Added external jar file to my project : Project> build path> configure build path> libraries > add external jars > added all jars here.

Execution:
Execute my test as "testNG suite" and error on driver initialization.

My code where driver is initialized:

```
package com.trantor.base;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class TestBaseSetup {

    private WebDriver driver;
    static String driverPath = "D:\\jars\\chromedriver_win32\\";

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    private void setDriver(String browserType, String appURL) {
        switch (browserType) {
        case "chrome":
            driver = initChromeDriver(appURL);
            break;
        case "firefox":
            driver = initFirefoxDriver(appURL);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("browser : " + browserType
                    + " is invalid, Launching Firefox as browser of choice..");
            driver = initFirefoxDriver(appURL);
        }
    }

    private static WebDriver initChromeDriver(String appURL) {
        System.out.println("Launching google chrome with new profile..");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath
                + "chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(appURL);
        return driver;
    }

    private static WebDriver initFirefoxDriver(String appURL) {
        System.out.println("Launching Firefox browser..");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(appURL);
        return driver;
    }

    @Parameters({ "browserType", "appURL" })
    @BeforeClass
    public void initializeTestBaseSetup(String browserType, String appURL) {
        try {
            setDriver(browserType, appURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error....." + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
 package com.trantor.authorportal.tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.trantor.authorportal.pageobjects.LoginPage;
import com.trantor.base.TestBaseSetup;

public class AuthorTestSuite1 extends TestBaseSetup{
        private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        driver=getDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyHomePage() {
        System.out.println("Home page test...");
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.verifyPageTitle(), "Home page title doesn't match");
    }

}
```

Comment: Added one line to FF driver initialization: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverPath + "geckodriver.exe");

Comment: But it throws error : [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd64 v= and igd10iumd64 v=
1497851375788 Marionette INFO Listening on port 56757
Jun 19, 2017 11:19:36 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession